# Need help scraping specific div elements from a website and exporting them into a CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

Im trying to scrape specific div elements from a website, and although the scraping does work. I can't exactly seem to workout how to export ALL the specified elements into a CSV. When I run the program, it prints out all the elements I want just fine, however when I check my CSV file it only exports one of the elements I'm looking for.

Sorry if this is a very noob question, and have been looking on StackOverFlow for a while now.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
#The website im scraping data from
URL = "urlhere"
r = requests.get(URL)

#
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

#specific elements that I want scraped
staff = soup.findAll("div", class_="col-12 staffListTableRow")


for nums in staff:
      staffNums = nums.find_all("div")[3]
      print(staffNums)
 


#Field names and rows for the CSV
fields = ['staff']
rows = [staffNums]

filename = "staff.csv"


# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you restructure your code so that you write each row to your file one at a time. Something like the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

filename = "staff.csv"
#The website I'm scraping data from
URL = "urlhere"
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(['staff'])   # write the header

    staff = soup.findAll("div", class_="col-12 staffListTableRow")

    for nums in staff:
        staffNums = nums.find_all("div")[3].text
        print(staffNums)
        csvwriter.writerow([staffNums])
```

Obviously this has not been tested as there is no URL to test with, but it should give you a different approach to try.